# How to render views for CI of Web-API and Knockout with Jasmine?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, continuous-integration, jasmine

**Problem/Question**

I want to include the rendered HTML from my views in the Jasmine test suites that run on my CI build so I can verify the Knockout bindings are not broken and the interaction with the view-model works as expected.  Is there an established method for doing this?

**My current setup:**

I have a application that is using MVC with Razor views, Web-API and Knockout.js with the MVVM pattern.  I want to add testing for the ever growing amount of JavaScript in the project.  I started by adding tests using Jasmine.  In my tests I created JSON objects to mock the data that would normally be provide by my Web-API calls.  I added the execution of the tests to by CI build.

So far so good, except I felt this wasn't a good integration test. If someone modified the structure of the data for a Web-API call the code may fail in production.  But the test would still pass because it is using static mock data.  The same was true if the view was changed.  The knockout binding could very well break and the tests wouldn't indicate that at all.

I was able to solve the problem of the static data.  There may be a better solution, but what I did was create an executable that serializes the same data that the Web-API method would return.  It saves that data to a .js file.  I added the executable as a build step.  I can then just load those .js files in my tests and use that data.  If the object that is being serialized by the Web-API/executable changes, the tests fail and my CI build goes red.

**Back to my problem:**

The point of my question is that I have not found a good solution for the problem of how to make my CI ensure the Knockout binding on my views stay in sync with the view-model?  My thought is to somehow render my razor view to an HTML file.  Then use that in the test for the Knockout binding.  I haven’t found a good method to do this though.

I have included some samples of how my tests are currently setup.  Testing the Knockout binding for this simple examples probably isn't necessary.  My real world view-models have much more logic that is dependent on the data and the binding though.  I would like to be able to test that.

I’m also open to any evidence that my whole approach is flawed and there is a better way to ensure all the pieces work together.

**Data that is written to .js file (JSON would normaly come from Web-API call)**

```
var customerData = { "ID": "123", "FirstName": "John", ... more data... }
```

**Jasmine test:**

```
describe("domain.myViewModel.test", function () {

    var vm;

    beforeEach(function () {
        vm = new myViewModel(customerData);
    });

    it("should should have some data", function () {
        //assert something
    });
}
```

**HTML File to load tests**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Jasmine Test Runner</title>
        <!-- include jasmine files here... -->
        <link href="/TestRunner/jasmine-1.3.1/jasmine.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script src="/TestRunner/jasmine-1.3.1/jasmine.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/TestRunner/jasmine-1.3.1/jasmine-html.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/TestRunner/jasmine.junit_reporter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <!-- include source files here... -->
        <script src="/jsscripts/views/productclass/domain.myViewModel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>       

        <!-- include test js files here... -->
        <script src="/DataScripts/customerData.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/Tests/domain.myViewModel.test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <!-- include jasmine.js files here... -->
        <script src="/TestRunner/executeJasmine.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>            
          // I want the HTML from by views here
          // So I can test the bindings and interactions work as expected
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is an interesting setup you're aiming for. I don't know if it'll work very well though, you're trying to use a unit-testing setup to do view / integration tests. It may be a lot easier to write a few Selenium integration tests to check your views and integration of VM's and views.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I'm not familiar with Selenium.  But based on few quick searches, it looks promising.